# lua torch, how to get the print() output into a string

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

```
require 'nn'
criterion = nn.ClassNLLCriterion()
print(criterion)
```

this outputs

```
nn.ClassNLLCriterion
{
  sizeAverage : true
  output : 0
  gradInput : DoubleTensor - empty
  output_tensor : DoubleTensor - size: 1
  target : LongTensor - size: 1
  total_weight_tensor : DoubleTensor - size: 1
}
```

I would like to get this print output for logging purposes. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I don't know torch but try `tostring(criterion)`.

Comment: `tostring(criterion)` gives only `nn.ClassNLLCriterion`, unfortunately without the additional informaiton

Comment: If no one else has an idea, then maybe look at how they redefined `print` or whether the `__tostring` of the criterion (if things still work that way) can be coaxed to spitting out the long version. That may require some digging into the source but should be doable. Try to see if `debug.getinfo( getmetatable( criterion ).__tostring, "S" )` works and produces some helpful info (you'll get a table with info, and if the `__tostring` is written in Lua, that will give you the file & line range; if C it'll just say "[C]"). (And maybe try the same getinfo on `print`.)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I'm not sure how you get this output. When I run this code I get `nn.ClassNLLCriterion`. Maybe different Lua/Torch versions?

Anyway, if you want to have this info in a string, you might have to extract it yourself. This can easily be done doing a simple loop:

```
for k,v in pairs(criterion) do
    print(k,v)
end
```

If you want the fancy print output then I suggest you look at TREPL's code (like @nobody suggested in the comments). It's all in Lua so it's very easy to replicate. More precisely, I recommend their [sizestr()](https://github.com/torch/trepl/blob/master/init.lua#L146), [print_new()](https://github.com/torch/trepl/blob/master/init.lua#L260) and [printvar()](https://github.com/torch/trepl/blob/master/init.lua#L167) functions. Simply change them so instead of printing, they construct a string.

A quick example using their sizestr function:

```
-- Copy/Paste from trepl/init.lua
local function sizestr(x)
  local strt = {}
  if _G.torch.typename(x):find('torch.*Storage') then
    return _G.torch.typename(x):match('torch%.(.+)') .. ' - size: ' .. x:size()
  end
  if x:nDimension() == 0 then
    table.insert(strt, _G.torch.typename(x):match('torch%.(.+)') .. ' - empty')
  else
    table.insert(strt, _G.torch.typename(x):match('torch%.(.+)') .. ' - size: ')
    for i=1,x:nDimension() do
      table.insert(strt, x:size(i))
      if i ~= x:nDimension() then
        table.insert(strt, 'x')
      end
    end
  end
  return table.concat(strt)
end


local function sutoringu(elem)
  local str = ''
  if torch.isTensor(elem) then
    str = sizestr(elem)
  else
    str = tostring(elem)
  end
  return str
end

local str = '{\n'
local tab = '  '
for k,v in pairs(criterion) do
  str = str .. tab .. k .. ' : ' .. sutoringu(v) .. '\n'
end
str = str .. '}'

print(str)
```

This outputs the same thing as what you wished for, constructing a string in the process. It's far from optimal but it's a start.